# Generating random vector for Full Homomorphic Cryptography

Tags: homomorphic-encryption

The site below explains that part of doing homomorphic encryption, you need to generate a vector of random numbers that have the property that its dot product against a randomly generated bit vector mod 2 has an absolute value less than some amount (but greater than zero).

http://windowsontheory.org/2012/05/02/building-the-swiss-army-knife/

Is there any way to generate such a vector other than brute force?  Seems like it could take a long time for a large vector.

Comment: Your question seems to be about full-homomorphic encryption, which is much more difficult to realize than simple homomorphic encryption. Maybe you should indicate this more clearly in your question.

Comment: It isn't, I'm just trying to figure out if there's a better way to generate the vector with this property than brute force (:

Comment: One does not need such a vector to do homomorphic encryption. Therefore people (like me) reading your question will wonder what you are talking about. I think if you specify 'full-homomorphic encryption', then it will be easier to understand why you need such a vector.

Comment: Is this site *creating* this homomorphic scheme or it is describing it and not citing the source?

Comment: It's basically a very summarized overview of Craig Gentry's paper
http://crypto.stanford.edu/craig/craig-thesis.pdf

Comment: @AlanWolfe: As mentioned at the end of the [first part](http://windowsontheory.org/2012/05/01/the-swiss-army-knife-of-cryptography/) the cited blog post is about an [FHE scheme](http://ia.cr/2012/078) by Zvika Brakerski (which is - relatively seen - much more practical than Gentry's original proposal).

Comment: Yeah. Trying to figure out the details of that post. Are you able to help? (:

Comment: @AlanWolfe: The two blog posts didn't help me much either. Are you interested in a particular FHE scheme or are you fine with learning any of them? Then you could take a look at [Homomorphic Evaluation of the AES Circuit](http://ia.cr/2012/099). Just skip the pieces about AES, and you have a nice introduction to BGV.

Comment: This question could be improved by splitting up / clarifying the first sentence; sentences should not take up 4 lines. Including the relevant parts of the provided linked document would be very helpful as well.

Answer (score -1):

After thinking about it here's what I think.  Let me know what you think.

First, I generate a random vector of floats and figure out what the dot product is.

I then pick one of the elements of the float vector that correspond to a 1 in the binary array (randomly?), and then adjust that value the necessary amount to make the dot product come out to the value I want.

Thoughts? Seems like it should be ok.

Comment: Also wanted to note, when doing this I realized a naiive implementation could cause some values in the vector to be pegged at 1 or -1 and that could let someone know that the key has a 1 in that bit index.  I'm currently thinking maybe only allowing to use up to half of the headroom available when adjusting an index to adjust the dot product.  Might be issues with that too though but not sure yet.  Like indices that correspond to a 1 in the secret key may tend to have higher absolute values maybe.

Comment: Why don't you just read the paper and see exactly how it's done, instead of guessing?

Comment: It says its easy to generate but doesn't elaborate